# How to register modules in Prism 6 WPF application with view-switching navigation?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I begin develop Prism 6 WPF view-switching application in MSVS 2015 Professional (russified). Below is my solution representation (I bag your pardon for Russian in my MSVS):

[image]

Below is Bootstrepper of my application:

```
class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

Both of my modules must be loaded with the application and each of them has Model in Models folder, View in Views folder and ViewModel in ViewModels folder. (In accordance with technical assignmen my application must have up to 20-22 such modules.) Application user will swithch these views by the radiobuttons in MainWindow's MainNavigationRegion. Below is MainWindow XAML (without radiobuttons):

```
<Window x:Class="FlowmeterConfigurator.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        Title="{Binding Title}" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
           <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Background="LightGray" MinWidth="250" Margin="5,0,0,5">
            <ItemsControl x:Name="NavigationItemsControl" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainNavigationRegion" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Padding="5" />
        </Border>
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainContentRegion" 
                    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5,0,5,5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

I beginner in Prism and my problem is: How to register my two modules (AuthorizationModule and CalibrationModule) in Bootstrepper class? Should I create my own class implementing IModuleCatalog? For example AggregateModuleCatalog:IModuleCatalog{...} and put in Bootstrepper the following code:

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
{
    return new AggregateModuleCatalog();
}
```

Or use Prism.Modularity.ConfigurationModuleCatalog and put in Bootstrepper the following code:

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
{
    return new ConfigurationModuleCatalog();
}
```

Now: Should I define ConfigureModuleCatalog method in Bootstrepper to show how each module is defined, downloaded and initialized? Like this:

```
protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
{
    // Module "Authorisation" is defined in the code.
    Type moduleAuthType = typeof(AuthorizationModule);
    ModuleCatalog.AddModule(new ModuleInfo(moduleAuthType.Name, moduleAuthType.AssemblyQualifiedName));
    // Module "Calibration" is defined in the code:
    Type moduleCalibrType = typeof(CalibrationModule);
    ModuleCatalog.AddModule(new ModuleInfo(moduleCalibrType.Name, moduleCalibrType.AssemblyQualifiedName));
}
```

And last: Should I configure UnityContainer and how? For example:

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
    base.ConfigureContainer();
    . . . . .
    // What code must I write here?
    . . . . .
}
```

I've read the following materials: 
1) View-Switching Navigation QuickStart Using the Prism Library 5.0 for WPF.
2) Modularity QuickStarts Using the Prism Library 5.0 for WPF.
3) Navigation Using the Prism Library 5.0 for WPF.
4) Modular Application Development Using Prism Library 5.0 for WPF. But due to my first acquaintance with Prism, I'm as beginner can't orientate in correct direction and ask for your help. So my question is: **How must I register my modules in my application?**

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, you have to register your Views as named objects in Unity.

Something like

```
Container.RegisterType<Object, FirstView>("FirstView");
Container.RegisterType<Object, SecondView>("SecondView");
```

or for Prism 6.0

```
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<FirstView>("FirstView");
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<SecondView>("SecondView");
```

alternatively you can directly register it (but the extension methods above are more convenient and readable)

```
Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(FirstView), "FirstView");
```

in either your `IModule.Initialize()` method (if the view is inside your Module) or in your bootstrapper (if the view is in your application).

The name you use can differ from the type name, i.e. `Container.RegisterType<Object, FirstView>("First");`. Just remember that the named string is the one used in navigation.

**Update: For Prism 6.0 it's `Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<FirstView>("First");`, see the [source](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Unity.Wpf/UnityExtensions.cs) **

So to navigate to this View, you'd use `regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", new Uri("First", UriKind.Relative));`.

This worked for Prism 5. It should still apply for Prism 6 though.

As an additional note, you can inject your `IUnityContainer` into your modules, so they can register their own objects.

```
namespace Module.MyModule
{
    [Module(ModuleName="MyModule", OnDemand=false)]
    public class MyModule : IModule
    {
        private readonly IUnityContainer container;

        public MyModule(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            if (container == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("container");

            this.container = container;
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            // Prism 6.0 uses RegisterTypeForNavigation from the Prism.Unity namespace
            this.container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<SecondView>("SecondView");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, each view is inside its module. So, for example, I must put Container.RegisterType<Object, AuthorizationView>("Authorization"); in AuthorizationModule.Initialize() ?

Comment: @Dr.Doog: Yes and use this string later to pass to the `Navigate` method

Comment: Tseng, You mean pass the string in RequestNavigate() method ?

Comment: Seems they have renamed it to `RegisterTypeForNavigation` (see https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Unity.Wpf/UnityExtensions.cs) For Prism 5 you need to import the ` using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions` namespace. I'll update my answer

Comment: @Dr.Doog: Updated answer, should work but can't test it at work right now

Comment: Should I add Prism.Unity assembly reference to each Module?

Comment: @Dr.Doog: Depends. If you need to use navigation from your modules, you'll need to add it anyways (for the `IRegionManager`). If you don't need any prism components, then avoid adding the reference just because of one extension method and use the `Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(FirstView), "FirstView")` variant `Container.RegisterType<Object,FirstView>("FirstView")` with `Microsoft.Practices.Unity` namespace (see unity 4 source at https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/blob/master/source/Unity/Src/UnityContainerExtensions.cs)

Comment: What does IMigrationTaskRegistrationService interface do?

Comment: Ignore it, it's something from my project I did a few months ago and didn't removed it when I copied over the example